# PHP mysqli_stmt::bind_param number of variables does not match

Tags: php, mysqli

While binding variable to my prepared statement PHP reports that the number of parameters do not match !

here is the code:

```
private $q_setQueue = "update rivr_queues set name='?', description='?' where QueueID='?';";
.
.
.
$stmt = $astdb->prepare($this->q_setQueue);
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$qName,$qDesc,$qID);
```

number of parameters is three so I think the code is correct.

Comment: You shouldn't wrap the `?` placeholder with single quotes (`''`) since it would be treated as a real value and not a placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting means that the amount of variables you're passing to the `bind_param` function isn't matching the amount of placeholders you have in your prepared query.

While you do have 3 variables and 3 "question marks" (keep on reading why I used that term and not "placeholders") in the prepared query - notice that when you're wrapping the suppose to be placeholders with single quotes (`''`) they would be treated as real values and not as placeholders.

So basically, you have 0 placeholders and 3 variables -> no match.
Removing the single quotes and updating the query:

```
private $q_setQueue = "update rivr_queues set name=?, description=? where QueueID=?;";
```

Should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
$stmt->bind_param(1,$qName);
$stmt->bind_param(2,$qDesc);
$stmt->bind_param(3,$qID);
```

and omit the single quote on every question mark `?`

Comment: The way the OP use the `bind_param` is fine, you don't have to split it. From the manual: `$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);`

Comment: Oh I see. thanks for correcting.. but this is what I prefer.. =)